# In my unit test sandbox. why is it telling me the function I'm specifying is a non-existent property?

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, chai, sinon, sinon-chai

The following line in my unit test:

> sandbox.stub(myAPI,'getPeople').returns([500, {errorCode: '500'}])

is giving me the following error:

> TypeError: Cannot stub non-existent property getPeople

I'm trying to stub an error response from my API call to test my error handling.

The unit test:

```
const chai = require('chai');
const sinonChai = require('sinon-chai');
const sinon = require('sinon');
const { getPeopleHandler } = require('../services/handlers/get-people-handler');
const { expect } = chai;
const myAPI = require('../services/api');

chai.use(sinonChai);

describe('handle error', () => {
    let req;
    let res;
    let sandbox;
    describe('getPeopleHandler() with error', () => {
        before(() => {
            req = {
                session: {}
            };
            res = {
                render: () => ({})
            };

            sandbox = sinon.createSandbox();
        });
        beforeEach(() => {
            sandbox.stub(myAPI,'getPeople').returns([500, {errorCode: '500'}]);
        })

        afterEach(() => {
            sandbox.restore();
        });

        it('should render the error page', async () => {
            sandbox.stub(res, 'render').returns({});
            res.locals = {};
            await getPeopleHandler(req, res);
            expect(res.render).to.have.been.calledOnceWith('error.html');
        });
    });
});
```

api.js

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch');

const getPeople = (url) => {
    console.log(`About to call API at ${url}`);
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        fetch(url, { method: 'GET' })
            .then(res => Promise.all([res.status, res.json()]))
            .then(([status, jsonData]) => {
                resolve([status, jsonData]);
            }).catch(error => {
                console.log('e', error)
                reject(error)
            })
    })
};

module.exports = getPeople;
```

get-people-handler.js

```
const callAPI = require('../../services/api');
const config = require('../../config/config');

const getPeopleHandler = async (req, res) => {
    const url = config.getPeopledataUrl;
    const response = await callAPI(url);
    console.log(`API call status = ${response[0]}`);
    if (response[0] === 200) {
        res.locals.list = response[1];
        res.render('people.html');
    } else {
        res.locals.error = response[0];
        res.render('error.html');
    }
};

module.exports = { getPeopleHandler };
```

Answer (score 0):

You are stub the `getPeople` function because you use `module.exports`. If you want to export a object, you should do it like this:

```js
module.exports = { getPeople };
```

`sinon.stub(object, "method")`

> Replaces `object.method` with a stub function. An exception is thrown if the property is not already a function.

Below is a working example:

`api.js`:

```js
const fetch = require('node-fetch');

const getPeople = (url) => {
  console.log(`About to call API at ${url}`);
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    fetch(url, { method: 'GET' })
      .then((res) => Promise.all([res.status, res.json()]))
      .then(([status, jsonData]) => {
        resolve([status, jsonData]);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log('e', error);
        reject(error);
      });
  });
};

module.exports = { getPeople };
```

`config.js`:

```js
module.exports = {
  getPeopledataUrl: 'http://localhost:3000/api/people',
};
```

`get-people-handler.js`:

```js
const api = require('./api');
const config = require('./config');

const getPeopleHandler = async (req, res) => {
  const url = config.getPeopledataUrl;
  const response = await api.getPeople(url);
  console.log(`API call status = ${response[0]}`);
  if (response[0] === 200) {
    res.locals.list = response[1];
    res.render('people.html');
  } else {
    res.locals.error = response[0];
    res.render('error.html');
  }
};

module.exports = { getPeopleHandler };
```

`get-people-handler.test.js`:

```js
const sinon = require('sinon');
const { getPeopleHandler } = require('./get-people-handler');
const myAPI = require('./api');

describe('handle error', () => {
  let req;
  let res;
  let sandbox;
  describe('getPeopleHandler() with error', () => {
    before(() => {
      req = {
        session: {},
      };
      res = {
        render: () => ({}),
      };

      sandbox = sinon.createSandbox();
    });
    beforeEach(() => {
      sandbox.stub(myAPI, 'getPeople').returns([500, { errorCode: '500' }]);
    });

    afterEach(() => {
      sandbox.restore();
    });

    it('should render the error page', async () => {
      sandbox.stub(res, 'render').returns({});
      res.locals = {};
      await getPeopleHandler(req, res);
      sinon.assert.calledWithExactly(res.render, 'error.html');
    });
  });
});
```

test result:

```
  handle error
    getPeopleHandler() with error
API call status = 500
      ✓ should render the error page


  1 passing (7ms)

-----------------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File                   | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
-----------------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files              |   60.87 |       50 |   16.67 |   60.87 |                   
 api.js                |      30 |      100 |       0 |      30 | 4-13              
 config.js             |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
 get-people-handler.js |   83.33 |       50 |     100 |   83.33 | 9-10              
-----------------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
```